# how to create a PersonalTab in MS teams App

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

i wonder how the hoisted angular web app on azure can be shown in teams tab. i only want to use the url of the hoisted webapp and showcase what is there in website as it in personal tab.

Any suggestion or proper approach will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

To display a hosted Angular web app in a Teams tab, you can create a Teams app with a personal tab that points to the URL of your hosted web app.
You can use the Teams Toolkit to create a new Teams app with a personal tab and update the `contentUrl` property of the personal tab to the URL of your web app.

```
"staticTabs": [
    {
        "entityId": "yourEntityId",
        "name": "Your Tab Name",
        "contentUrl": "https://your-angular-web-app.azurewebsites.net",
        "scopes": ["personal"]
    }
]
```

Please note that your Angular web app must allow itself to be iframed by Teams which can be done by setting the X-Frame-Options and Content-Security-Policy HTTP response headers appropriately in your web app.